# Web service calls doesnt cancel when text changes in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield, alamofire

I am searching a text from the service when I type in `UITextField`. I am using `Alamofire` library to do service calls. And this is how I call my web service calling function.

```
func search(){

    self.strSkipCount="0"
    com.showProgress()
    self.searchDirectory() { (status) in

        print("-----SEARCHING-----")
        self.com.removeProgress()
        if(status){
            self.facesCarousel.reloadData()
            self.setNumberofFaces(count: self.arrayDirectory.count)
        } else {
            self.com.showProgress()
            self.getStaffData() { (status) in
                self.com.removeProgress()
                if(status){
                    self.facesCarousel.reloadData()
                    self.setNumberofFaces(count: self.arrayDirectory.count)
                    self.resetMembercountLabel()
                } else {
                    self.setNumberofFaces(count: self.arrayDirectory.count)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my `ViewDidLoad()`I have set the target to my text field in this way.

```
txtSearch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.searchTextFieldEditingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
```

Then

```
func searchTextFieldEditingChanged() {
    if(txtSearch.text != ""){
        self.searchText=txtSearch.text
        //self.cancelPreviousRequest()
       NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(search), object: nil)
        self.search()
    } else {
        self.searchText=""
         NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(searchDirectory(callback:)), object: nil)
        isSearching=false
        prevIndex=0
        self.arrayDirectory=self.arrayPreviouslyLoadedArray
        facesCarousel.reloadData()
        self.resetMembercountLabel()
        self.com.removeProgress()
    }
}
```

My problem is, Lets say I want to search the name "Alex",Even after found the alex my previous service calls seems not stopping. And it reload with a wrong result. but sometimes it works. Also when delete all the text in the text field and if the text is "" in the textfield. I want to reload with initially loaded dataset. But service calls doesn't stop immidiately after set to "". Please help me.